# How to capture a character and "repeat it" for the next match?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have this text and I need to extract all the compasses (which are represented by the `|`, `:|`, ... etc)

```
X:1
T:Paddy O'Rafferty
C:Trad.
M:6/8
K:D
dff cee|def gfe|dff cee|dfe dBA|dff cee|def gfe|faf gfe|1 dfe dBA:|2 dfe dcB|]
~A3 B3|gfe fdB|AFA B2c|dfe dcB|~A3 ~B3|efe efg|faf gfe|1 dfe dcB:|2 dfe dBA|]
fAA eAA|def gfe|fAA eAA|dfe dBA|fAA eAA|def gfe|faf gfe|dfe dBA:|
```

Right now I have the following regular expression:

```
/([\|\[].+?[\|\]])/m
```

Which works every other compass because the `[\|\]]` this token "consumed" the character.

I'd like to capture the compasses in this manner:

```
|def gfe|
|dff cee|
|dfe dBA|
|dff cee|
|def gfe|
|faf gfe|
|1 dfe dBA:|
|2 dfe dcB|]
```

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html   Here is a description of similar operations in RUBY

Comment: Since the | character is only serving as a visual and syntactic separator in this instance, you don't really need to capture it, do you? You could just capture the set {'def gfe','dff cee','dfe dBA', (...), '1 dfe dBA:','2 dfe dcB'|} and assume the bar character. (good tune, btw)

Comment: the thing is that the | separator can come bundled with other caracters (ex: [|, ||, |:, :|, ..., etc ) , so i do need to capture them.

Comment: @ViktorJusto  Something like this? I am unclear of your expected result. https://eval.in/215994

Comment: @hwnd yes that's really close to what I'm looking for. give me a second I'm studying your regexp.

Comment: @hwnd Id like to know more about using the lookaheads to capture matches. do you know of any blog posts that go deeper into that topic?
i found my regex based on your response but as you can see the captures are good but the "matches" are shown weird.
http://rubular.com/r/ritud9t47q

Comment: The ends of the first two lines throw a spanner into the works. Your regex returns `"|2 dfe dBA|"` for the end of the second line. Based on your example for the first line, I presume that should be `"|2 dfe dBA|]"`. Where are the regex gurus when we need them?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Is the OP wanting to keep the delimiters? | .. | and are the sections at the beginning of the string included in the match results? Perhaps something like this? https://eval.in/216022

Comment: @hwnd, that was my assumption, going by the example output. Compare your results to the output for the end of the first line (`|2 dfe dcB|` vs `|2 dfe dcB|]`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [String#scan](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-scan) to return an `Array` of all matches.

eg:

```
 text = 'your long text up there'
 text.scan(/([\|\[].+?[\|\]])/m)
```

The above returns:

```
[["|def gfe|"], ["|dfe dBA|"], ["|def gfe|"], ["|1 dfe dBA:|"], ["|]\n~A3 B3|"], ]...], [...]]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: In the first line, this does return either instance of `"|dff cee|"`
or `|2 dfe dcB|]`. I haven't check the other two lines.

Comment: -1, not because the answer is wrong, because you let it stand knowing it was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of ways you could do that.

**#1 Use [String#split](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/String.html#method-i-split) on each line, then fix the end of the line.**

```
def split_em(str)
  arr = str.split(?|).map { |s| "|#{s}|" }
  arr[-1] << (arr.pop).tr(?|,'') unless str[-1] == ?|
  arr
end

split_em("dff cee|def gfe|dff cee|dfe dBA|dff cee|def gfe|faf gfe|1 dfe dBA:|2 dfe dcB|]")
  #=> ["|dff cee|", "|def gfe|", "|dff cee|", "|dfe dBA|", "|dff cee|",
  #    "|def gfe|", "|faf gfe|", "|1 dfe dBA:|", "|2 dfe dcB|]"]
split_em("~A3 B3|gfe fdB|AFA B2c|dfe dcB|~A3 ~B3|efe efg|faf gfe|1 dfe dcB:|2 dfe dBA|]")
  #=> ["|~A3 B3|", "|gfe fdB|", "|AFA B2c|", "|dfe dcB|", "|~A3 ~B3|",
  #    "|efe efg|", "|faf gfe|", "|1 dfe dcB:|", "|2 dfe dBA|]"]
split_em("fAA eAA|def gfe|fAA eAA|dfe dBA|fAA eAA|def gfe|faf gfe|dfe dBA:|")
  #=> ["|fAA eAA|", "|def gfe|", "|fAA eAA|", "|dfe dBA|",
  #    "|fAA eAA|", "|def gfe|", "|faf gfe|", "|dfe dBA:|"]
```

**#2 Apply a regular expression to each line to create an array, then modify each element of the array**

```
def split_em(str)
  str.scan(/(?<=^|\|).+?\|(?:[^|]*?$)?/).map { |s| "|#{s}" }
end
```

- `(?<=^|\|)` is a positive lookbehind which matches the beginning of line or `|`.
- `.+?` grabs one or more characters non-greedily (so as to not gobble up the rest of the line), then matches `|`, then, if present (the `?` for the non-capture group), zero more characters other than `|` up to the end of the line.
- `map` adds `|` to the beginning of each string in the array.

Open challenge for improvements to the regex:

- rather than apply it to each line, apply it to the string containing all there lines, returning an array containing an array of strings for each line.
- eliminate `map`.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed from the comments and examples provided that you don't want to capture compasses at the beginning of a line, maybe because is does not have `|` on the left side, also the results always have only `|` on the left side, `[|, ||, |:, :|, ..., etc` on the right side.
try this pattern:

```
(?<=[\]:|])([^|\r\n]+\|[:\]]?)
```

The thing is, you can not capture the same character by the same capturing group twice, so you have to give up capturing `|` on the left side and add it later using your scripting language.

```
(?<=[\]:|])     # a look-behind for any of "]:|"
(               # capture gourp 1
    [^|\r\n]+   # anything that is not one of "|\r\n"
    \|          # followed by "|"
    [:\]]?      # followed by and optional one of ":]"
)               # end of capture group 1
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/89)
Hope it helps